# Plotting after assigning parameter values

Tags: plotting

I have a function of a single variable with other parameters.

```
f[x_] := 
  -2*a + a (Log[(x^2 + c2^2)^2/(4*x*c2^2)]) + 4*x*c2*a/(x^2 + c2^2);
```

I want to plot `f` by varying `x`, while assigning specific values to `c2` and `a`.

I tried:

```
Plot[f[x] /@ a -> 100 /. c2 -> 1, {x, 0, 1, 0.01}]
```

but it doesn't work.

Also if I were to evaluate for a list of `c2` and `a`, how will the code change?

Comment: `/.` not `/@` and `{x,0,1}`.

Comment: Also, it is generally quicker to use a list of replacements instead of doing each replacement consecutively.

Comment: Keeping in mind @Kuba comment, you can try this `Plot[f[x] /. {a -> 100, c2 -> 1}, {x, 0, 1}]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably the easiest way to answer you question is to redefine your function as a function of three variables and then write a [`Manipulate`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Manipulate.html) expression that will allow you to explore the parameter space with respect to `a` and `c2`.

```
f[c2_, a_, x_] := 
  -2 a + a (Log[(x^2 + c2^2)^2/(4 x c2^2)]) + 4 x c2 a/(x^2 + c2^2)

Manipulate[
  Plot[f[c, a, x], {x, 0, 1},
    PlotRange -> {Automatic, {-650, 600}}],
  {{a, 100}, 25, 200, 25, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
  {{c, 1.}, .1, 2., .1, Appearance -> "Labeled"}]
```

Then you will get an interactive panel where you can vary `a` and `c2` and what the variation does to the shape of `f`.

[image: demo]

Answer (score 2):

For the second part of your question one can use `Table`

```
Table[f[x], {a, {100, 200}}, {c2, {1, 3, 5}}]

(* {{-200 + (400 x)/(1 + x^2) + 
   100 Log[(1 + x^2)^2/(4 x)], -200 + (1200 x)/(9 + x^2) + 
   100 Log[(9 + x^2)^2/(36 x)], -200 + (2000 x)/(25 + x^2) + 
   100 Log[(25 + x^2)^2/(100 x)]}, {-400 + (800 x)/(1 + x^2) + 
   200 Log[(1 + x^2)^2/(4 x)], -400 + (2400 x)/(9 + x^2) + 
   200 Log[(9 + x^2)^2/(36 x)], -400 + (4000 x)/(25 + x^2) + 
   200 Log[(25 + x^2)^2/(100 x)]}} *)
```

You would add `x` values if you wanted it evaluated numerically

```
Table[f[x], {x, 0.1, 1, 0.1}, {a, {100, 200}}, {c2, {1, 3, 5}}]

(* {{{-66.7769, 124.892, 221.593}, {-133.554, 249.784, 
   443.187}}, {{-92.9184, 69.4724, 160.496}, {-185.837, 138.945, 
   320.992}}, {{-90.9049, 43.0843, 128.288}, {-181.81, 86.1687, 
   256.576}}, {{-79.3853, 28.6482, 107.96}, {-158.771, 57.2963, 
   215.919}}, {{-64.686, 20.7524, 94.1669}, {-129.372, 41.5048, 
   188.334}}, {{-49.5793, 16.9428, 84.5188}, {-99.1587, 33.8856, 
   169.038}}, {{-35.2873, 15.8775, 77.7312}, {-70.5745, 31.7551, 
   155.462}}, {{-22.2539, 16.7317, 73.0306}, {-44.5078, 33.4635, 
   146.061}}, {{-10.533, 18.9564, 69.9118}, {-21.066, 37.9127, 
   139.824}}, {{0., 22.1651, 68.0254}, {0., 44.3302, 136.051}}} *)
```